# kml stacked bar chart within marker

Tags: charts, kml, bar-chart

I want to include a stacked bar chart in a KML file marker ~ say four topics, North, South, East, West with three "stacked" bar charts, Lower, Middle, Higher for each topic.

I have found this code which works well for a standard bar chart but I lack the skills to modify it into a stacked chart.  Can anyone provide a working KML stacked bar chart example that will work in Google Earth using KML scripting only?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name />
    <visibility>1</visibility>
    <Snippet>Relationship versus Pizza</Snippet>
    <description><![CDATA[<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&
chs=200x150&chd=t:10,15,25,13,3,35&
chxt=x,x&chxl=0:|Jul|Aug|Sept|Oct|Nov|Dec|1:|Start|||Thanksgiving||Breakup&
chtt=Pizza%20Deliveries|by%20Relationship%20Progress"/>]]></description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-74.01490535558324,40.70396174218289,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

Code Source: http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.co.uk/2007/12/using-chart-api-in-kml-for-quick-data.html

Comment: OK, I have a second question;  This bit chs=200x150 can be changed e.g. chs=400x150 to change the size of the x-axis.  Why does it not work like this chs=200x300 to change the Y-axis?

Comment: and a third question ~ the x-axis is set to 100 and I have data both above and below 100.  How can I set the X-axis to the max data available?

Comment: and a fourth question; How to show this as a pie chart?